# SCR vs diode VI characteristics

Tags: diodes, scr

We know in an SCR when in conduction mode, triggered by some gate voltage, the lower three junctions will essentially turn into a single N junction and so the SCR essentially becomes a PN junction diode type element.

Is it safe to assume after conduction starts and onwards that the SCR's VI characteristics will be the same as that of a diode? Because the VI graph of an SCR looks like a PN junction diode when conduction starts.

Comment: I wouldn't ignore all the other layers of silicon in a SCR, but an SCR does have a relatively fixed voltage drop across it when conducting like a diode does. I do not follow what you mean when you say the three lower elements turn into a single N junction. A piece of P-doped doesn't suddenly turn into an N-doped region just like it doesn't in a BJT.

Comment: @DKNguyen if we apply directly voltage across the terminals of an SCR then will the" pattern " of current changes according to the applied voltage will be same as of diode?

Answer (score 1):

Is an SCR VI curve the same as a diode? Look at some curves from datasheets. I tried to pick components with similar current capabilities.

I would say that the VI curve is similar, but not the same. At very low currents, a diode voltage drop is smaller than an SCR, and the drop seems to be approaching zero faster.

In the "on" state, an SCR has two series P-N junctions conducting, that is part of the reason. Why an SCR voltage drop approaches zero slower, I don't know.

There may be someone here who knows semiconductor physics well enough to explain the technical reasons.

[image]

https://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/1n4148.pdf
[https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Solid%20State%20INC%20PDF's/2N2322-29-22A-29A-C5U-C5D-TO39-ssi.pdf](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Solid%20State%20INC%20PDF%27s/2N2322-29-22A-29A-C5U-C5D-TO39-ssi.pdf)

Note that since the current is on a log scale, the shape is not the upward turning curve that most of us are more familiar with.

Comment: A good way to see an SCR, behaviorally, is shown [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hCAZT.png). Just FYI.